# Can't install PyGObject on macOS

Tags: python, macos, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I'm using macOS
Python versions: 2.7 / 3.6

**pip3 :**

```
$ pip3 install PyGObject
Collecting PyGObject
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyGObject (from versions:)
No matching distribution found for PyGObject
```

Same result for pip and pip2.x

Why can't I find it?
What's the alternative way installing PyGObject on macOS?

Comment: Check faq [link](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html)

Comment: @Howaboutnope tried that way before, doesnt works! it gives back a tons of erros in the `pip install ..` part

Answer (score 4):

Try to use

```
brew install pygobject3
```